# Updating image depending on value in the database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am building a dice system for practise purpose

Everytime I double click the dice at the moment it generates a new number from 1-6 and adds it to the database with an ID that autoincrements

The database looks like this:
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3plf.png)

What I want to do is make it so whatever the last value is in the database it shows an image for example if the last number was 6 show an image of a dice with a 6 on it. I know I could just make it so upon double click it changes the image but I can only think of how I would do it client side and not update for everyone on the website that is viewing the dice.

Comment: You say "I would do it client side and not update for everyone on the website that is viewing the dice." Do you intent for everyone to see the new dice image as soon as it is double clicked? If so, you need to look into sockets to support that behavior.

Comment: I'll look into sockets, thanks.

What I meant was I know how to make the image update client side when they double click it but I don't know how to make it update for everyone viewing the website